# wexpect equivalent for logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect, wexpect

I have the following codes using pexpect in linux it is ok.

```py
import pexpect 

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh test@ip' % (susername, ip) , encoding='utf-8')
child.logfile = open("{}/{}.txt".format(folder, ip),"w")
```

when have tried to change to wexpect to be used in windows but the logfile is empty
my goal is to write everything the wexpect spawn into a logfile from start to end

i have tried

```py
import wexpect

logging =""
child = wexpect.spawn('ssh -c aes256-cbc %s@%s' % (username, ip) , encoding='utf-8' , logfile=logging)
print(logging)
child.logfile = open("{}/{}.txt".format(folder, ip),"w")
```

but print is empty as well.

All other `wexpect` functions seems to be working fine, I am able to use `.sendline`, `.expect` function.

checking if anyone know how to get the logging to work
don't seems to have many documentation on it

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the [wexpect repo](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/tree/master/wexpect), and the only code that handles the `logfile` argument is in the [legacy module](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/blob/master/wexpect/legacy_wexpect.py) (the `read_nonblocking()` and `send()` methods in the `spawn_windows` class), so it doesn't looks like `logfile` works right now.

I tried `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn`, but I had SSH problems. May I suggest you try `paramiko`?

> **NOTE**
>
> - Tested on Windows 11, using Python 3.9 and Parmiko 2.9
> - Added `aes256-cbc` to my remote VM's `sshd_config` to match your connection. BTW, you can place multiple ciphers in the `Transport` tuple, as long as they're on both devices (I use `Get-TlsCipherSuite | Format-Table -Property CipherSuite, Name` on Windows).

```
import paramiko

ip_address = "192.168.x.xxx"
username = "stack"
password = "**********"

list_of_commands = ["which ssh", "date", "whoami", ]

paramiko.Transport._preferred_ciphers = ("aes256-cbc", )
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip_address, username=username, password=password)
for c in list_of_commands:
    print("Command:", c)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(c)
    print("Output:\n", stdout.read().decode())
print("Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output:**

```
Command: which ssh
Output:
 /usr/bin/ssh

Command: date
Output:
 Tue 11 Jan 2022 06:36:34 PM EST

Command: whoami
Output:
 stack

Script complete. Have a nice day.
```

Comment: the reason for using pexpect or wexpect module, i will need to detect regex return string before entering the next command.



eg: show tech will take a long time to finish running before entering the next command

thanks for the help to recommend paramiko